# two left outer join not working Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

There are four table in the query
Table a    contains **a_id**    , a_name
Table a_tl contains **a_tl_id** , a_id    , language_id , a_disp_name
Table b    contains **b_id**    , a_id    , b_name
Table b_tl contains **b_tl_id** , b_id    , language_id , b_disp_name

I want to do a left outer join on a and a_tl , a leftouter join on b and b_tl
and a inner join on the resultant tables .I wrote the following query

```
SELECT    case  a.a_disp_name
                WHEN   null  THEN  a.a_name
                else         a.a_disp_name
          end   AS           a_name             ,
          case  b.b_disp_name
                WHEN   null  THEN  b.b_name
                else         b.b_disp_name
          end   AS           b_name             ,
          a_id                                  ,
          b_id                                  
FROM      a                                     ,
          a_tl                                  ,
          b                                     ,
          b_tl                 
WHERE     a.a_id = a_tl.a_id (+)
AND       b.b_id = b_tl.b_id (+)
AND       a_tl.language_id = 2    
AND       b_tl.language_id = 2     
AND       a.a_id= b.b_id
```

This query is working of the language_id is present in the database if for a particular value it is not present it will not work i.e. left outer join is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is, that you are not using `(+)` for your `language_id` checks.
Your table is outer-joined, so `language_id` is `NULL` when no record is found, but then you check for `language_id = 2`, but ? `language_id` is `NULL`.

I also don't see where you use results from `a_tl` or `b_tl`, guess that's just a problem of your post, not your original query?

---

However, please use explicit joins instead of the old syntax. Once you are used to it, it is a lot easier to read and understand.
Your query could also benefit from using [`COALESCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) (or `NVL` if you like):

```
SELECT COALESCE( a_tl.a_disp_name, a.a_name ) AS a_name,
       COALESCE( b_tl.b_disp_name, b.b_name ) AS b_name,
       a.a_id,
       b.b_id
FROM a
JOIN b ON ( b.b_id = a.a_id )
LEFT JOIN a_tl ON ( a_tl.a_id = a.a_id AND a_tl.language_id = 2 )
LEFT JOIN b_tl ON ( b_tl.b_id = b.b_id AND b_tl.language_id = 2 )
```

Hope I got your question right, please ask if it does not work.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation where I can learn about the syntax of multiple joins.I am not able to understand why have you used a_tl and b_tl and not a ,b  `LEFT JOIN a_tl ON ( a_tl.a_id = a.a_id AND a_tl.language_id = 2 )
LEFT JOIN b_tl ON ( b_tl.b_id = b.b_id AND b_tl.language_id = 2 )`

Comment: Here is the [`JOINS` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm). Not sure what you mean by *multiple joins*. Do you mean the two conditions? Every condition that is required for the outer join to succeed is put there. Do you mean my two `LEFT JOIN`s? You can join as many tables as you need.

Comment: In the query that you have written .I was getting a bit confused about the order in which the joins will be performed because there is no parenthesis .Is it like the last join will be performed first and then the one on top of it?

Comment: The best join order is determined by Oracle (also with your syntax). In this case, I would assume that it starts by joining `a` and `b`, followed by the two outer joins. I'm afraid I still don't understand your worries, does my query work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `a_tl.language_id = 2` you force an inner join(a_tl.language_id would never be null).

If you want to left join only with rows from a_tl with a_tl.language_id = 2, then write like this:

```
FROM      a 
          join b on (a.a_id= b.b_id)
          left join a_tl on ( a.a_id = a_tl.a_id and a_tl.language_id = 2)
          left join b_tl on ( b.b_id = b_tl.b_id and b_tl.language_id = 2 )
```