# 2 Outer Joins on Same Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Here is a question which has been boggling me for few days now, and I searched and searched but couldn't find any convincing answer !

Simple question, why is it restricted to have 2 Outer Joins in SQL, on same table even with different columns being used, check the queries below for better understanding. Also I can overcome them using nested sub query or ANSI joins, but then why it is even restricted in the first place using (+) operator!

In this question I'm referring to the error :

> ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table

What I want to ask is why this is allowed :

```
select * from
a, b, c
where a.a1 = b.b1
and a.a2 = c.c1
```

And why this is not allowed:

```
select * from
a, b, c
where a.a1(+) = b.b1
and a.a2(+) = c.c1
```

Please leave ANSI and Nested SubQueries alone

Comment: Can you supply an example of what you are trying to do?  You should be able to join (`inner` or `outer`) the same table as many times as needed...

Comment: As @sgeddes said, you are most likely confused. There is no "2 Outer Joins" limit on Oracle

Comment: I believe you'll only get this if you're doing an "old-style" outer join using the `(+)` operator.  Do not use the `(+)` operator - it's non-portable and may well be deprecated by Oracle.  Instead, use an ANSI-style LEFT OUTER JOIN to perform your joins.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: It has been answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095930/two-left-outer-join-not-working-oracle-sql

Comment: Cross posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44601

Comment: @BobJarvis: the old syntax for outer joins (using `(+)`) ***is*** deprecated and should not be used any longer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's certainly not recommended any more, even by Oracle. Are you sure it is deprecated? I can't find anything in the Oracle docs about it.

Comment: @ypercube: from the manual "*Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator*". Sounds to me like "deprecated": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#i2054062

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I wasn't certain of the status of `(+)` - is it "not recommended" or "deprecated" or "gosh, we sure wish you wouldn't use this anymore but we'll keep supporting it until icicles dangle from Satan's gutters, plus 10 years", which is why I weasel-worded my earlier comment.  That and a lack of time to look it up (it's summertime, and that means camp for kids, and that means hours on the road hauling them across two states to deliver them and pick them up.  Kids - love 'em or love 'em, you gotta love 'em :-)

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO. The linked question asks how to get around the restriction. This question asks the reason for the restriction.

Answer (score 10):

The restriction is described in Oracle documentation: [Outer Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354)

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following **rules and restrictions**, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax:
>
> ...
>
> In a query that performs outer joins of more than two pairs of tables, a single table can be the null-generated table for only one other table. For this reason, you cannot apply the (+) operator to columns of B in the join condition for A and B and the join condition for B and C. Refer to SELECT for the syntax for an outer join.

which basically means (described in ANSI/ISO syntax) that you can't have with the old `(+)` syntax what is perfectly valid in ANSI/ISO:

```
--- Query 1 ---
  a 
RIGHT JOIN b
  ON a.x = b.x
RIGHT JOIN c 
  ON a.y = c.y
```

or:

```
--- Query 1b ---
  c 
LEFT JOIN 
    b LEFT JOIN a
        ON a.x = b.x 
  ON a.y = c.y
```

That's only one of the many restrictions of the old Oracle syntax.

---

As for the reasons for this restriction, it may be implementation details or/and the ambiguity of such joins. While the two joins above are 100% equivalent, the following is not equivalent to the above two:

```
--- Query 2 ---
  a 
RIGHT JOIN c 
  ON a.y = c.y 
RIGHT JOIN b
  ON a.x = b.x
```

See the test in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a338/1).** So the question arises. How should the proprietary join be interpreted, as query 1 or 2?

```
FROM a, b, c 
WHERE a.y (+) = c.y 
  AND a.x (+) = b.x
```

---

There is no restriction if a table appears on the left side of (2 or more) outer joins. These are perfectly valid, even with the old syntax:

```
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.x = b.x 
  LEFT JOIN c ON a.y = c.y
  ...
  LEFT JOIN z ON a.q = z.q

FROM a, b, ..., z
WHERE a.x = b.x (+) 
  AND a.y = c.y (+)
  ...
  AND a.q = z.q (+)
```

Comment: This restriction seems to have been relaxed in 12c

Comment: @shonkylinuxuser Link to this? I would think that they would remove support for the old syntax, not enhance it.

Comment: @ypercube The link is [https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT492](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT492) but my comment was based on my experience. I have 10g and 12c databases that have the same data and schema, a query with multiple (+) joins works in 12c, fails in 10g with the ORA-01417 error above.
Personally I find the old syntax easier to digest when there are more than a couple of joined tables.

Comment: @shonkylinuxuser Interesting! Can you share a gist or pastebin with a query that works in 12c and fails in 10g? I still think that the proprietray syntax `(+)` for outer joins is ambiguous. And I see nothing in the Oracle docs that they have resolved that.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thnx, I didn't know that. I will check your examples

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use explicit `OUTER JOIN` syntax. Starting from Oracle 12c this restriction is relaxed [1.4.3 Enhanced Oracle Native LEFT OUTER JOIN Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT152):

> In previous releases of Oracle Database, in a query that performed outer joins of more than two pairs of tables, a single table could be the null-generated table for only one other table. **Beginning with Oracle Database 12c, a single table can be the null-generated table for multiple tables.**

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE a AS
SELECT 1 AS a1, 2 AS a2 FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE b AS
SELECT 1 AS b1 FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE c AS
SELECT 3 AS c1 FROM dual;

-- Oracle 12c: code below will work
SELECT * 
FROM a, b, c
WHERE a.a1(+) = b.b1
  AND a.a2(+) = c.c1;
```

Output:

```
A1  A2  B1  C1
-   -   1   3
```

**[db<>fiddle demo - Oracle 11g will return error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6899420eae3a35222832fb2feea75960)**

**[db<>fiddle demo Oracle 12c/18c will return resultset](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76fa222b0cd9bc5cc1b488e99f805ce5)**

Comment: The documentation is not clear. What is the meaning of such a join?