# SQL query - link to lookup with two fields at once

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'd like to put together a query that links two fields from the THERAPY table to my lookup table REF_CODE; field PROT (which can be null) and field THER_TYPE (which is non-null). REF_CODE contains multiple look up categories, distinguished by CAT_ID. My query at the moment looks like this:

```
SELECT THER_ID, r1.CODE_NAME, r2.CODE_NAME
FROM THER t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r1 ON t.PROT = r1.CODE
JOIN REF_CODE r2 ON t.THER_TYPE = r2.CODE
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234
AND r1.CAT_ID = '1'
AND r2.CAT_ID = '2';
```

There are two THERAPY records where EVENT_ID = 1234. This query only returns the records where PROT is not null. The record where PROT = null isn't returned at all.

Why is this? How can I return all the values, regardless of whether PROT is null or not?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Using Oracle 11g by the way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT THER_ID, r1.CODE_NAME, r2.CODE_NAME
FROM THER t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r1 ON t.PROT = r1.CODE
and r1.CAT_ID = '1'
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r2 ON t.THER_TYPE = r2.CODE
AND r2.CAT_ID = '2'
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234;
```

---

Following are the change I made to your code:

1. You are doing an `INNER JOIN` in your **2nd JOIN** with `REF_CODE` hence the `NULL` values would drop off the result. I changed it to a `LEFT JOIN`
2. Your second issue boils down to the placement of your `filter criteria` in `ON` and `WHERE` clauses.

*Explanation of the 2nd point:*

In an `INNER JOIN`, you could use the `ON` and `WHERE` interchangebly. The underlying logic doesn't change and it also doesn't have an impact of the execution plan as well.

Its quite different for the `OUTER JOINs`. As you can see in your case a misplaced filter can skew the logic completely.

a. `Filter Criteria in the WHERE Clause` i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM A left join B
ON A.id=B.id
WHERE B.id=1
```

The above query will function like an `INNER JOIN` and limit the entire result only to the row with `B.id=1` (Note that the filter is applied to the table on the right of the `LEFT JOIN` operator)

b. `Filter Criteria in the ON Clause` i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM A left join B
ON A.id=B.id
AND B.id=1
```

The above query will only limit the rows of `table B` as they are being mapped to `table A` in the `LEFT JOIN` operator. So the result will contain **all rows** of `table A` and values in the columns for `table B` only for the rows that match the condition `B.id=1`

Comment: Thanks SoulTrain...but I'm afraid this still doesn't bring back the record where PROT = null. Not sure what I'm missing here...!

Comment: I think I know what is causing your scenario. Can you try the updated code and see if it works. I will explain the changes, if it works.

Comment: Your `Where` clause was limiting the result set. Check the updated code.

Comment: SoulTrain, that is excellent! The query seems very similar to me...just the WHERE clause is in a different place. Could you explain more about why this works?

Comment: Sure... I will explain shortly.

Comment: @SoulTrain +1 Nice explanation of the left join / where clause problem.  This really is a common misunderstanding. I added your query to my SQL Fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b2f/4

Answer (score 1):

I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60119/5) query to test your question.  Please review to verify that it matches your scenario.

The where clause is trumping the left join.  Move the two filters on Cat_ID into the join clauses like this:

```
SELECT THER_ID, r1.CODE_NAME, r2.CODE_NAME as Name2
FROM THER t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r1 ON t.PROT = r1.CODE AND r1.CAT_ID = '1'
JOIN REF_CODE r2 ON t.THER_TYPE = r2.CODE AND r2.CAT_ID = '2'
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234;
```

The other less clean way to do this is to surround the part of the where clause related to the left join with `isnull()` like this:

```
SELECT THER_ID, r1.CODE_NAME, r2.CODE_NAME as Name2
FROM THER t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r1 ON t.PROT = r1.CODE
JOIN REF_CODE r2 ON t.THER_TYPE = r2.CODE AND r2.CAT_ID = '2'
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234
AND Coalesce(RTRIM(r1.CAT_ID),'1') = '1'
```

See this similar answer for [Left Outer Join Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22719158/edit).

Additional:

If @SoulTrain's query worked, then you must also have rows in **Ther** that do no match rows in **Ref_Code**.  In that case you do need to use two left joins, but the order of the joins do not matter.  Please see [updated SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b2f/4) to see this query in action.  It is the last query.

```
SELECT THER_ID, r1.CODE_NAME, r2.CODE_NAME
FROM THER t
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r1 ON t.PROT = r1.CODE and r1.Cat_ID = 1
LEFT JOIN REF_CODE r2 ON t.THER_TYPE = r2.CODE AND r2.CAT_ID = '2'
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1234;
```

Comment: Hi Abraham. The first example doesn't work unfortunately - still excludes the record where PROT = null. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer help http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096237/269123 ? The only thing he seems to do differently is that he uses parenthesis on the join clauses. Let me know if this helps and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I see no reason why this statement should not get the desired records. Moving the criteria to the on clause solves the issue. Join order doesn't matter here. There is no relation from r1 to r2. davemere, your problem lies somewhere else. Do you get the records when you remove r2 from the query? Or do you get them when removing r1? Check this and think over your query.

Comment: @davemere - I added a SQL Fiddle sample to imitate the scenario that you describe.  Please see the link.  Also I corrected the syntax of the second query to use Coalesce instead of ISNULL.  Does this help?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for backing me up.  There must be something else going on in the data.

Comment: Hi guys - SoulTrain posted some SQL below which works as intended. I'm not clear exactly what's different, but the ordering of the statements is important. Moving the WHERE clause, and the AND clause seems to be significant.

Comment: Please see updated answer.  Let me know if the last query does or doesn't work.